# $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^R e^{x^2 - R^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I think
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^R e^{x^2 - R^2}dx = 0$$ but  I cannot show it. It is easy to see that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^{R-\epsilon} e^{x^2 - R^2}dx = 0$$ but then I cannot justify interchanging limits in
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^R e^{x^2 - R^2}dx = \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_0^{R-\epsilon} e^{x^2 - R^2}dx = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^{R-\epsilon} e^{x^2 - R^2}dx = 0$$
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$\int_0^Re^{x^2-R^2}dx=\int_0^{R-\epsilon}e^{x^2-R^2}dx+\int_{R-\epsilon}^Re^{x^2-R^2}dx\le \int_0^{R-\epsilon}e^{x^2-R^2}dx+\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 11):

There is another way: L'Hospital's Rule Can be applied here.
Note that

$$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^R e^{x^2-R^2}dx = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_0^R e^{x^2}dx}{e^{R^2}}$$

Note that both numerator and denominator are differentiable and both tend to infinity.
By L'Hospital's rule, you get
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^R e^{x^2-R^2}dx = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{R^2}}{2Re^{R^2}} = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2R} = 0$$

Comment: This is quite nice too. Thanks